# TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null at MongoClient.connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am following a tutorial and I want to seed a database using npm run command but my code is throwing an error

> const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null
>       at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\menad\Documents\angular\pro-delivery\src\server\data\seed-db.js:13:31)

This is my seed-db.js file content

```
require('dotenv').config();

const users = require('./users');
const orders = require('./orders');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');   

function seedCollection(collectionName, initialRecords) {
MongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_CONN, (err, db) => {
    console.log('connected to mongodb...');

    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);

    collection.remove();

    initialRecords.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.password) {
            item.password = bcrypt.hashSync(item.password, 10);
        }
    });

    collection.insertMany(initialRecords, (err, result) => {
        console.log(`${result.insertedCount} records inserted.`);
        console.log('closing connection...');
        db.close();
        console.log('done.');
    });
});
}

seedCollection('users', users);
seedCollection('orders', orders);
```

This is my environment file

```
DB_CONN=mongodb://username:password@ds117200.mlab.com:17200/db-name
```

When i run the command `npm run seed` connection to database is ok but then i get the error `cannot read property 'collection' of null...`

What am I missing or not doing right? The collections users.json and orders.json files are is the same directory as the seed-db.js file.

Comment: You're ignoring errors. Check it before try to access database.

Comment: You probably installed the latest `mongodb` node driver series of 3.x but you're following old tutorials/examples using the 2.x series of the driver. You don't get a `Database` object in the `MongoClient.connect()` response anymore. See [Connecting](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/connect/) in the official guide for the updated syntax.

Comment: @NeilLunn You are right about the mongodb driver version. However I have not been able to make sense of how to work with the new version of the driver when using remote serve like mlab. I have included my .env file. What do I do in a situation like this?